# SSIS / Oracle Attunity for Integration Services

Tags: sql-server, oracle, ssis, sql-server-data-tools, attunity

Thanks ahead of time for the assist!

I'm currently undergoing an investigation into slow loading times using SSIS to transfer data from our Oracle servers to SQL (Part of a Data warehouse effort) and we're suffering from extremely slow loading times.

After some research into the issue I've come across the Attunity connectors and these seem to be what we need to try, as we're using the built-in connectors that are just slow/not recommended for use.

I have since had the guys managing the servers to install the correct package from here:

- [Microsoft Connectors for Oracle and Teradata by Attunity for Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/attunity-connectors?view=sql-server-2017)

And now I seek to use the new connectors in Visual Studio 2013 Pro(Version 12.0.21005.1 / .NET Framework 4.7.03190)/SSDT. SQL itself is the 2016 flavor - Version 13.0.16106.4.

Long story short. I can't seem to find/enable/use the new Attunity connectors. Are there any trouble shooting tricks available that may help resolve this issue or just allow its proper use?

Thank again!

Comment: Hi @jonathan, you need to have a license unless you are on SQL Enterprise, and install the connectors on the dev machine 1st, then the server

Comment: Which version of SQL server do you have? Attunity works for Enterprise and Developer versions.  if you provide this info I might be able to help